# STM32F103CB Timer update interrupt not working

Tags: stm32, c

I am trying to setup the timer update interrupt of a stm32f103cb. My setup and interrupt code looks as following:

```
void TIM2_IRQHandler(void)
{
    GPIOB->BSRR = 1UL << 1; // turn on led, works if function is called manually
    TIM2->SR = ~1;
}

void setup(void)
{
    RCC->APB1ENR |= 1; // enable clock for TIM2

    TIM2->PSC = 71;
    TIM2->ARR = 0xFFFF;

    NVIC->ISER[0] |= TIM2_IRQn; //TIM2_IRQn == 28
    NVIC->IP[7] |= 2 << 4;

    TIM2->SR = 0;
    TIM2->CNT = 0;
    TIM2->DIER = 1; // enable update interrupt

    TIM2->CR1 = 1; // enable timer
}
```

From my understanding TIM2_IRQHandler should be called, everytime the timer updates, but that does not happen. Some things i know:

- The rest of the programm runs fine, the interrupt is just never triggered
- The timer is running
- The update interrupt flag in TIM2->SR is getting set correctly, everytime the timer updates

Am i forgetting something in the setup or is the error somewhere else ?

Comment: Is the timer working at all?  Can you poll it and see if the value is changing?

Comment: I polled the timer and the value is changing

Comment: Is there something like a global interrupt enable?

Comment: Always clear the interrupt flag (i.e. set the `SR`) as early as possible in the ISR, or the interrupt might be triggered again endlessly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
NVIC->ISER[0] |= TIM2_IRQn;
```

should be

```
NVIC->ISER[0] = 1UL << TIM2_IRQn;
```

because to enable the interrupt you want to set bit 28, not write 28 as bit value to the register. Now it works as expected.

Comment: It should be `NVIC->ISER[TIM2_IRQn/32]`, in case the interrupt number is larger than 31.

Comment: Please mark your own answer so that it is shown as "accepted" in the lists. @Erlkoenig It has to be `TIM2_IRQn % 32`. Since I don't use that controller I don't know, but the header file might already define the correct value even for interrupts in ISER1 and ISER2.

Comment: @thebusybee No, the `% 32` would have to go on the right side: `NVIC->ISER[TIM2_IRQn/32] = (1 << (TIM2_IRQn%32));`. [This is](https://github.com/ARM-software/CMSIS_5/blob/develop/CMSIS/Core/Include/core_cm3.h#L1508) is what ARM does, but using bitwise operations instead of arithmetic to make it less readable. [This](https://www.mikrocontroller.net/articles/ARM-ASM-Tutorial#Peripheral_interrupts) is an example in assembly doing the same thing.

Comment: @Erlkoenig Right, I wrote my comment too fast. Thanks for clarifying!